# How to reload and clear all catched datas on visit to home page?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

In my application, there is multiple page exist. user can go from 1st page to last page filling out the forms. since one form is depends others, I am saving those values in shared service object as well.

now, when the user click to go back to home page, all the service object values, and forms need to reset back to their default or null. how can i achieve this?

I find a way as `window.location.reload()` - but this refresh the application total. what is the correct `angular` approach?

`this.router.navigate([''], 'forcetoreload')` - or something else?

any one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can juse use router.naviagate and call your service method to clear the stored values.

You should have a method to clear the values as

```
clearValues():void {
   this.storageValues = [];
}
```

and then in component,

```
this.router.navigate(['/home');
this.myService.clearValues();
```

Comment: That's not just a array to clear, I have multiple objects with their values. how to clear the object(s)?

Comment: probably you should store them in one object and call  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/clear